# Process started by Java ProcessBuilder not being destroyed

Tags: java, cmd, process, subprocess, processbuilder

I'm working with the Java ProcessBuilder (JDK 8). 
The Process is started as follows.

```
public Process createProcess(RunnableImplementation runnableImplementation) throws IOException {
    String command = runnableImplementation.command();

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    processBuilder.directory(new File(runnableImplementation.executionFolderPath()));
    processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    //global var
    process = processBuilder.start();

    return process;
}
```

My command executes a Ruby script, which executes other Ruby scripts.
When I'm trying to stop the created Process, at least I expect the parent process to be stopped, but it's not. That confuses me, because the following method returns true.

```
public boolean killProcess() {

    System.out.println("Trying to stop the running process, this can take a while");
    boolean success = false;

    if (process != null && process.isAlive()) {
        //global var
        process.destroyForcibly();
        try {
            success = process.waitFor(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            System.out.println("The process was successfully stopped");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Waiting for the process to stop was interrupted, it is no longer possible to ensure that all subprocesses are stopped cleanly");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Nothing to stop");

    }
    return success;
}
```

The waitFor method in the Process class.

```
    /**
 * Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the
 * subprocess represented by this {@code Process} object has
 * terminated, or the specified waiting time elapses.
 *
 * <p>If the subprocess has already terminated then this method returns
 * immediately with the value {@code true}.  If the process has not
 * terminated and the timeout value is less than, or equal to, zero, then
 * this method returns immediately with the value {@code false}.
 *
 * <p>The default implementation of this methods polls the {@code exitValue}
 * to check if the process has terminated. Concrete implementations of this
 * class are strongly encouraged to override this method with a more
 * efficient implementation.
 *
 * @param timeout the maximum time to wait
 * @param unit the time unit of the {@code timeout} argument
 * @return {@code true} if the subprocess has exited and {@code false} if
 *         the waiting time elapsed before the subprocess has exited.
 * @throws InterruptedException if the current thread is interrupted
 *         while waiting.
 * @throws NullPointerException if unit is null
 * @since 1.8
 */
public boolean waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
    throws InterruptedException
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    long rem = unit.toNanos(timeout);

    do {
        try {
            exitValue();
            return true;
        } catch(IllegalThreadStateException ex) {
            if (rem > 0)
                Thread.sleep(
                    Math.min(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(rem) + 1, 100));
        }
        rem = unit.toNanos(timeout) - (System.nanoTime() - startTime);
    } while (rem > 0);
    return false;
}
```

Why I know that the process is not stopped:
If I start my Ruby process over the Windows Cmd, I can see how two Ruby processes appear (Windows Task Manager) - if I close the Cmd window or press ctrl + c, they'll disappear. When I start the script via Java and execute my killProcess method, they won't disappear, I have to stop them manually.

**I want to stop the main process and all it's child process, how can I do that?** I thought about tracking PID's.

Comment: I believe you shoud only use ```destroyForcibly()``` if ```destroy()``` failed after a reasonable timeout

Comment: @Corentin I followed your suggestion, did not change anything.

Comment: If you aren’t providing input to the child process or reading its output, you should call `processBuilder.inheritIO();` before starting your process, so it doesn’t get stuck waiting for its output buffer to be drained.

Comment: @VGR I know the problem with the Buffered Reader readLine method, which in some cases blocks the thread. I've solved this by capping the creation and destruction of the process in a separate class (Read ouput in class A, handle process in class B). So that can't be the problem, but thanks for the tip.